# utf8 data looks fine in mysql but is broken in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I'm setting a rails environment up for one of my colleagues, who's using a mac (in case that's relevant).  I've pulled the data down from our live mysql database and made a local development database with that data.  If i open the mysql console, and look at the data for a record which has extended charset characters in its name field, then it looks fine.  However, in the rails console (and in a rails-generated web page) the encoding is broken: an endash is replaced by "â€”" for example.

The only rails config options i know about that are relevant to this is in config/database.yml.  I currently have this set:

```
encoding: utf8
collation: utf8_general_ci
```

which makes it work fine on my machine for example.  But like i say it's not working on my colleague's machine.  Any ideas anyone?

EDIT 1:  on the live server, where i copied the data FROM, the charset info looks like this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_connection | latin1                     | 
| character_set_database   | latin1                     | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | latin1                     | 
| character_set_server     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

EDIT 2:  in response to @eggyal's comment i've done a couple of mysqldumps, which has been quite revealing.  Here's the first dump:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -h127.0.0.1  dbname lessons --where="id=79510"
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: e_learning_resource_v3
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.32-Debian_7etch4-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `lessons`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lessons`;
CREATE TABLE `lessons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `description` text,
  `user_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `created_at` datetime default NULL,
  `privacy` int(11) default '1',
  `is_official` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `is_readonly` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `comments_allowed` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `hours` int(11) default NULL,
  `sessions` int(11) default NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `custom_menu_swf` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `pupil_liked_at` datetime default NULL,
  `user_liked_at` datetime default NULL,
  `pupil_favorite_count` int(11) default '0',
  `user_favorite_count` int(11) default '0',
  `teacher_notes` text,
  `pupil_notes` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `lessons`
--
-- WHERE:  id=79510

LOCK TABLES `lessons` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lessons` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `lessons` VALUES (79510,'Jazzâ€“Man',NULL,NULL,'2014-04-03 12:08:05',1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2014-04-03 12:08:05',NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lessons` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2014-04-03 11:16:42
```

So, this was just a straight mysqldump and it's got the broken character in it (Jazzâ€“Man) in the "INSERT INTO lessons" line.

I do it again with some extra options, and the data looks ok in the dump file:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -h127.0.0.1  dbname lessons --extended-insert --single-transaction --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset --where="id=79510" 
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: e_learning_resource_v3
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.32-Debian_7etch4-log
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `lessons`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lessons`;
CREATE TABLE `lessons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `description` text,
  `user_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `created_at` datetime default NULL,
  `privacy` int(11) default '1',
  `is_official` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `is_readonly` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `comments_allowed` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `hours` int(11) default NULL,
  `sessions` int(11) default NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `custom_menu_swf` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `pupil_liked_at` datetime default NULL,
  `user_liked_at` datetime default NULL,
  `pupil_favorite_count` int(11) default '0',
  `user_favorite_count` int(11) default '0',
  `teacher_notes` text,
  `pupil_notes` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `lessons`
--
-- WHERE:  id=79510

LOCK TABLES `lessons` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lessons` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `lessons` VALUES (79510,'Jazz–Man',NULL,NULL,'2014-04-03 12:08:05',1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2014-04-03 12:08:05',NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lessons` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2014-04-03 11:18:20
```

So, it looks like the extra options did the trick:

```
--extended-insert --single-transaction --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset
```

Comment: what is the original collation on your live mysql database ?

Comment: I'm looking in the conf file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on the server and there's no setting in there.  I've gone into mysql and looked in there:  the results are too much for a comment so i've edited my OP.

Comment: How did you export the data from the original database?

Comment: what is the output for `show table status` on your database ?  are all tables use latin1 collation ? If yes, then may be changing collation from utf8_general_ci to latin1_general_ci might help solve the issue. let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks @Jayaram.  Do you mean change the collation on my colleagues database, ie where the data is copied **to**, to be `latin1_general_ci`?  What does this collation option actually do?

Comment: I'm not sure that I have a very good picture of what is going on.  Are you and your colleague using the same database and Rails instances, your own independent Rails instances backed by the same database, or two entirely independent installations?

Comment: There is a server, with our production database.  Myself and my colleague both have local rails installations, each with their own local database.  I can copy the production db dump onto my machine and import it to mysql and it's fine, but when i do the same on my colleague's machine the problem occurs.  I am using linux and my colleague is on a mac, in case that's relevant.  thanks!

Comment: In rails `config/database.yml` make sure to set `encoding: utf8` for all desired environments (development, testing, production).

Comment: How have you obtained the production db dump, and how have you then imported it into your colleague's MySQL instance?  In particular, does it contain a command (e.g. `SET NAMES`) that configured the character set of the connection over which it was executed, or was that character set specified in any other way during the import process?  If neither, then it is possible that your colleague's MySQL client was configured with a different default character set to yours during the respective database imports thereby resulting in misencoded data.

Comment: @mind-404: i've done that, see my OP

Comment: @eggyal - yes, i think it's something like that: i changed my colleagues mysql conf, and restarted mysqld, but i guess that hasn't fixed it.  I've tried the following: 1) on the server, doing a straight mysqldump (with no extra options), then just pushing the resulting file into the db with `mysql -u root dbname < dumpfile.sql`.  and 2) the same, but passing these options to mysqldump: `--extended-insert --single-transaction --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset`.  In this second case, the characters also look messed up in mysql.

Comment: Can you reduce your dumpfile to a [short, self contained, correct example](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: See my OP.  This has actually fixed itself now - see my answer below.  Thank you very much for your help though.

Comment: BTW @eggyal, if you want to do an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks Max.  Any chance I might get the bounty too?  ;)

Comment: oh yes, sorry, i thought it applied it automatically when I marked your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a MySQL client interacts with the server:

1. the server receives any text merely as a string of bytes; the client will have previously told it how such text would be encoded.
2. if the server then has to store that text in a table, it must transcode it to the encoding of the relevant column (if different).
3. if the client subsequently wants to retrieve such text, the server must transcode it to the encoding expected by the client.

If the encodings used by the client in steps 1 and 3 are the *same* (which is usually the case, especially when the client in both cases is the same application), then it often goes unnoticed if the client is using an encoding other than the one it said it would.  For example, suppose the client tells MySQL that it will use `latin1`, but actually sends data in `utf8`:

- The string `'Jazz–Man'` is sent to the server in UTF-8 as `0x4a617a7ae280934d616e`.
- MySQL, decoding those bytes in Windows-1252, understands them to represent the string `'Jazzâ€“Man'`.
- To store in a `utf8` column, MySQL transcodes the string to its UTF-8 encoding `0x4a617a7ac3a2e282ace2809c4d616e`.  This can be verified by using `SELECT HEX(name) FROM lessons WHERE id=79510`.
- When the client retrieves the value, MySQL thinks that it wants it in `latin1` and so transcodes to the Windows-1252 encoding `0x4a617a7ae280934d616e`.
- When the client receives those bytes, it decodes them as UTF-8 and therefore understands the string to be `'Jazz–Man'`.

**Conclusion**: the client doesn't realise anything is wrong.  Problems are only detected when a different client (one that does not misstate its UTF-8 connection as `latin1`) tries to use the table.  In your case, this occurred when mysqldump obtained an export of the data; using the `--default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset` options effectively forced mysqldump to behave in the same broken way as your application, so it ended up with correctly encoded data.

To fix your issue going forward, you must:

1. Configure your application so that it correctly sets its MySQL connection character set (e.g. set `encoding: utf8` in `config/database.yml` for Rails);
2. Recode the data in your database, e.g. `UPDATE lessons SET name = BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1)` (note that this must be done for every misencoded text column).

Also note that you will probably want to perform these two actions atomically, which may require some thought.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by semi-accident.  When i was trying to import the sql data that had been done with the extra options relating to LATIN1 (see Edit 3 on my OP) i was getting an error message about the LC_TYPE variable (I didn't make a note of this exact error unfortunately).  A bit of googling led me to set the following variables in his ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

After setting this, and opening a new console tab, i was able to import the data.  But, it still looked wrong (though in a different way to before:  ie some other messed up characters replacing the endash for example.)  I scratched my head then did something else for a while.

Now, after he has restarted his laptop several times (because it's been a couple of weeks), it is all magically working.  So, i think that a reboot fixed it.  So, the answer is, i think, this:

Set these options in your rails `config/database.yml` file

```
encoding: utf8
collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Add these environment variables to `~/.bash_profile`

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Add (or change if they are there already) these options to your mysql config (in this case, `/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/my.cnf` but a more common location would be `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/etc/my.cnf` - look for it with `locate my.cnf`)

```
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Now reboot your machine.

Then, when you do mysqldump, make sure you do it with these options (in addition to whatever other options you have)

```
--extended-insert --single-transaction --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset
```

Some of this may not be necessary, but i think it was all necessary for me!

Thanks to everyone who commented for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do what you did.  It is interesting that the original dumpfile contained `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;`, which should have set the importing connection's character set to UTF-8.  It would appear that the problem may in fact lie in the production database.  What is the result of `SELECT HEX(name) FROM lessons WHERE id=79510` when run on the production/live db?

Comment: It's `4A617A7AC3A2E282ACE2809C4D616E`

Comment: That indicates that the EN DASH is encoded in the production server as `0xC3A2E282ACE2809C`, which is the UTF-8 encoding of `'â€“'` (which, when encoded in Windows-1252, yields the UTF-8 encoding of an EN DASH i.e. `0xe28093`).  In other words, it appears as though your live application is submitting UTF-8 encoded data to the production database whilst the database connection character set is set to `latin1` or similar.  You really should fix this!

Comment: ah... thanks for the info, that's really helpful.  And a top tip with the HEX() thing as well.  I think it must be the live config to blame: see EDIT 1

Comment: I'm not sure that your EDIT 4 has added anything new.  The [connection character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) is set by the client when it connects to the server.  It seems that your live application is not setting it correctly.  Fixing this will require two steps: (1) fixing the application; and (2) fixing the data in the database.

Comment: I can't speak for (1) as I don't know your live application; if it's also Rails, then it would seem that the relevant `encoding` line is not correctly set to `utf8` in the live `database.yml`.  As for (2), you need, for each string column, to: `UPDATE lessons SET name = BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1)` (where `latin1` is the connection character set that was previously used by the application).

Comment: Yes, sorry, i realised EDIT 4 was the same as EDIT 1 after i did it!  You're right about database.yml - it's not set to utf8 on the server.  Thanks for the update syntax, i will do this to a copy of the db on our server and if it's cool then do it on the original.  Thanks a lot!